# Test (Check) SERVER Connection

Tags: javascript, android, connection

How can i check a server connection? In an app i want to check if there's connection to the server and in case that the server's not working i can show a message using a toast or something, if there's connection the app continues as normal. I was attempting to do this with the following code, but i haven't had results.

Using this code im able to show a message only when the server's working but not otherwise.

```
public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
try{
URL myUrl = new URL(url);
URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
connection.connect();
return true;
} catch (Exception e) {
AlertDialogErrorServer(Reportes.this.getContext(), "conectado!", "tarde", true);
// Handle your exceptions
return false;
 }
}
```

and i was doing something like this:

```
if(!isConnectedToServer("http://appserver.eco.mx/movil/LanLong.php",5)){
    AlertDialogErrorServer(Reportes.this.getContext(), "¡No conectado!", "Lo sentimos por el momento la aplicación no está disponible, inténtalo más tarde", true);
}else { 
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `isConnectedToServer()` Well.... where is the code?

Comment: Sorry, i just edited my post @greenapps

Comment: Dud you handleyour exception? What are the results you have?

Comment: on that part i added a alertdialog to show, and it does, but i don't know how to show the message when there's no conection, so that's why i used "if (!isConnectedToServer)" but the message only appears when there's conection @greenapps

Comment: I dont see such message. Where are you talking about?

Comment: @greenapps i edited again the post